# Node executable can't be found in Visual Studio Code

Tags: node.js, path, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code to (try to) debug my node.js scripts. On the moment I want to debug my index.js file, Visual Studio Code says 'Cannot find runtime 'node' on PATH. Is 'node' installed?

And the answer to this question is 'yes', because it can be found in my 'usr/local/bin' folder. And when I execute the commando 'echo $PATH' in my bash terminal, then I see this path is included (among others):
echo $PATH
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/{myName}/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Have also done some google searches on the issue but haven't been able to find a sound solution.

Can you please help?

Hans

For background info: I have installed Visual Studio Code via Anaconda and I'm using a Mac on 10.13.6 (MacOS Sierra).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rather hoped there would be an answer better than the one I am about to give. For me over on Ubuntu 19.04, going through the install process for node fixed the issue; in my case, the PATH variable on my system was correct, and everything in `./.vscode/launch.json` was correct. Defeated, I decided to reinstall node, and suddenly debugging worked despite the PATH being exactly the same afterwards. Never thought I would be debugging my debugger!